# Winforms window close time

Tags: winforms, vsto, dispose

I'm working on a VSTO application (Excel Addin), on this application I have a window with some labels, buttons, and a `TreeView`. The `TreeView` can be populated with a huge amount of `TreeNode` items.

When it's populated with around a million items it takes about 40 seconds to close the window.
while closing the window for the rest of the application.
While closing - the rest of the application remaining unresponsive.

**My questions**:
Is there a way to close the window and remain responsive?
Is there a way to make it faster to close?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the virtualization of items in `TreeView` control is only supported in WPF platform.

WinForms must clean system resources for all million items so it takes a while.